Traefik, keycloak forward auth doesn't work on my .Net service
I am for sure doing some things badly, my goal would be to use traefik to forward auth requests to my services with keycloak, with the sample paste bin in my browser it works (it requires keycloak login) But I want to be able to auth the api requests too to my services running in .net,
also I found that I could hide them behind traefik so they shouldn't even need to requires ssl/httpS because they sit behind the authorization process,
Currently when I generate an accesstoken and put it in postman for the bearer token I still get returned the keycloak login page as response, is it a keycloak setup or a docker compose setup issue?
Also do I need to put [Authorize] on my controllers if I have already added the keycloak middleware on the service as forward auth? here is my docker-compose:
secrets:
  cloudflare-token:
    file: "./secrets/cloudflare-token.secret"
  cloudflare-email:
    file: "./secrets/cloudflare-email.secret"    
   
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.11"
    restart: always
    container_name: "traefik"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --api.dashboard=true
      #- --insecureSkipVerify=true
      # Set up LetsEncrypt certificate resolver
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare
      - --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnschallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1:53,1.0.0.1:53
      - --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnschallenge.delayBeforeCheck=20
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=[myemail]@gmail.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
      # staging environment of LE, remove for real certs
      #- --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caserver=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      # Set up an insecure listener that redirects all traffic to TLS
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
      # - --entrypoints.websecure.http.middlewares=traefik-forward-auth
      # Set up the TLS configuration for our websecure listener
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certResolver=letsencrypt
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.domains[0].main=mydomain.com
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.domains[0].sans=*.mydomain.com
    secrets:
      - "cloudflare-token"
      - "cloudflare-email"
    environment:
      - "CF_DNS_API_TOKEN_FILE=/run/secrets/cloudflare-token"
      - "CF_API_EMAIL_FILE=/run/secrets/cloudflare-email"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./certs:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.dev.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"      
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=user:{SHA}Et6pb+wgWTVmq3VpLJlJWWgzrck="

  paste-bin:
    container_name: paste-bin
    image: ghcr.io/enchant97/hasty-paste:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - traefik-forward-auth
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - 'traefik.http.routers.paste.rule=Host(`paste.dev.mydomain.com`)'
      - "traefik.http.routers.paste.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.paste.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"   
      - "traefik.http.routers.paste.middlewares=forwardauth"

  traefik-forward-auth:
    image: mesosphere/traefik-forward-auth
    container_name: traefik-forward-auth
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - keycloak
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
      - SECRET=secret
      - PROVIDER_URI=https://keycloak.dev.mydomain.com/realms/myrealm
      - CLIENT_ID=flutter-client
      - CLIENT_SECRET=secrettt
      - COOKIE_DOMAIN=https://dev.mydomain.com
      - DISABLE_SSL_VERIFICATION=true
      - INSECURE_COOKIE=1
      - ENCRYPTION_KEY=key
      - SCOPE=profile email openid
    networks:
        - mynetwork
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.traefik-forward-auth.loadbalancer.server.port=4181"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-forward-auth.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-forward-auth.middlewares=forwardauth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.forwardauth.forwardauth.address=http://traefik-forward-auth:4181"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.forwardauth.forwardauth.authResponseHeaders=X-Forwarded-User"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.forwardauth.forwardauth.trustForwardHeader=true"

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0
    container_name: keycloak
    hostname: keycloak
    environment:
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://keycloakdb/keycloak
      - KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
      - KC_DB_SCHEMA=public
      - KC_LOG_LEVEL=info
      - KC_FEATURES=docker
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
      - KC_PROXY=edge
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - keycloakdb
    labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`keycloak.dev.mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
    entrypoint: ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev"]

  events:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}eventsapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Events/Events.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - "EventBusSettings:HostAddress=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.events.rule=Host(`api.dev.mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api/events`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.events.middlewares=forwardauth"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq

I tried multiple settings yet couldn't find the right ones
